# ondragstart event with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to use Javascript Drag and Drop API.

```
var file = document.getElementById('file');
file.addEventListener('dragstart', function(evt){
  evt.dataTransfer.setData("DownloadURL",fileDetails);
}, false);
```

That works and all, but is there any way to use jQuery "on" to catch the event? I've tried

```
$('#file').on('dragstart', function(evt) {
   console.log(evt.dataTransfer);                    // this returns undefined
   evt.dataTransfer.data("DownloadURL",fileDetails); // so this produces error
});
```

But it doesn't work.

If possible, I don't want to use jQuery draggable plugin, since I'm not really looking to have a cross-browser solution.

Thanks

Comment: `evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer`

Comment: thanks! Can you add an answer so I can mark yours as the correct one?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use the property `originalEvent` of the jquery event to access native properties of the javascript listener, like this:

```
evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer
```

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the corrected code sample to make it clear how your answer is used in the OPs issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#file').on('dragstart', function(evt) {
   console.log(evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer);                    
   evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.data("DownloadURL",fileDetails); 
});
```