# How can I access the JQuery originalEvent attribute

Tags: scala.js

I want to handle drag and drop events using the JQuery on() method. So I tried to do the following:

```
element.on("dragstart", { (event: JQueryEventObject) =>
  val dragEvent = event.asInstanceOf[DragEvent]
  dragEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(...) 
})
```

But dataTransfer is undefined when I try to access it. I found a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697382/ondragstart-event-with-jquery). However the JQueryEventObject has no such *originalEvent* attribute so how can I access it?

NOTE. I am using the [jquery-facade](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade) library for my JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like jquery-facade (erroneously) does not declare `originalEvent`. For the long term, you may want to send a pull request to that repo to add it.

In the meantime, you can force your way through with some more dynamism:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import org.scalajs.dom

val originalEvent = dragEvent.asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].originalEvent.asInstanceOf[dom.DragEvent]
originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(...)
```